# UIStoryBoard Auto Layout embed UIStackView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I'm having a problem design my ViewController which contain a some Label and a ImageView. I have embed them in a StackView. My objective is to place a StackView inside a ScrollView so that my content will be scrollable if the content is longer then the screen height

So basically what I have done is

1 - Place a UIScrollView in a scene. Pin the scroll view to its superview without margins.

2 - Place a UIStackView inside the scroll view. Pin all sides of the stack view to the scroll view without margins (yes this is counterintuitive).

3 - Vertical scrolling: Add an equal widths constraint between the scroll view and the stack view

Here is my setting in storyboard

[image]

But I'm getting this red warning constrains. Anyone know how to fix this? Maythanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try example given at this Link It is using following steps

1. Create a UIScrollView, and set its constraints.
2. Add a UIStackView to the UIScrollView
3. Set the constraints: Leading, Trailing, Top & Bottom should be equal
   to the ones from UIScrollView
4. Set up an equal Width constraint between the UIStackView and
   UIScrollView.
5. Set Axis = Vertical, Alignment = Fill, Distribution = Equal Spacing,
   and Spacing = 0 on the UIStackView

   https://github.com/ar-juan/uistackview-in-uiscrollview

Comment: thanks, i you give a more detail? how can we add view inside and what constrains should we give?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh I have edited the Answer please take a look.

Comment: Thanks A lot. It work now. The trick is to set the StackView attribute. can ask what is the Distribution = Equal Spacing different from other option like fill, fill equally, fill proportionally and equal Centering

Comment: Equal Spacing is there will be equal space in between every element.Check Below Link, https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/22/uistackview-distribution/